# camera position relative to World coordinate

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am taking the Computer Vision course, and I had some problems while doing some exercise:
I have the intrinsic matrix K, and extrinsic matrix [R|t] of a camera as followings,

K =

`478.989 2.67423 405.437`

`0 476.472  306.35`

`0       0       1`

[R|t] =

`0.681951 -0.00771052   -0.734232    -46.1881`

`-0.344648    0.882047   -0.331892    -42.4157`

`0.645105    0.479386    0.598855     118.637`

[the real world coordination is shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh08y.png)

I want to calculate "camera position relative to World coordinate",
and the answer is supposed to be 
**[X, Y, Z] = [74.18, 69.421, 50.904]**

How can I get the answer? It just took me a lot of time, but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This OpenCV [document](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) details how to convert from world to camera co-ordinates.

x = K[R T]X

where x is 2D image co-ordinates and X is 3D world co-ordinate. Using above what you want is X which is nothing but:

X = inverse(K[R T]) * x

Now, put your values of x (u, v, 1) and you should get the value of X which is your required 3D co-ordinate.